# Not all pageviews not appearing in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have a website with around 100 page views / minute (as seen in my real time data overview. However, when I generate a report it says I've only had 15 page views. How do i get the pageviews/minute metric in a report so that the numbers are right?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you checked the pageviews report right after opening the real-time report?

Don't forget that to Free Google Analytics accounts it takes 24-48 hours for processing the data, to Premium GA accounts it takes 4 hours.

After that time go to Behavior > Site Content > All pages report and check if the data is right.

Regards, 
Vítor Capretz